# How to access a column by name from ResultSet of an INNER JOIN - duplicate column names?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

Using JDBC and SQLite, the ResultSet obtained from a SELECT with an INNER JOIN may contain duplicate column-names, e.g.

```
SELECT A.id, B.id FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (A.id=B.ref)
```

How can I get the `A.id` and `B.id`?

p.s. I can see that `ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData()` does contain the table name for each column, referenced by column number. But I can't see how to tell `rs.getString(...)` to give me `A.id` etc.

Comment: use aliases if both have the same name

Comment: oh you mean in the SQL? Ok that's a solution.

Comment: Or retrieve by index instead of by name. The JDBC API explicitly [documents this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html).